# Error 401 on Axios/InertiaJS request (Heroku)

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I deployed my website on heroku. It has a chat system and works locally but when deploying to Heroku the request that returns me all the users returns instead an error 401.
`GET https://website.herokuapp.com/api/user/me 401 (Unauthorized)`

I tried to remove the `auth:sanctum` from the api route but nothing changed.
I'll give some of the code below.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function(){
    Route::get('/user/me', [UserController::class, 'me'])->name('users.me');
});
```

```
public function me()
    {
        $userLogged = Auth::user();

        return response()->json(
            [
                'user' => $userLogged,
            ],
            Response::HTTP_OK
        );
    }
```

And on the web console I get a `message: "Unauthenticated."` in the network area

PS: If it helps I used this article to deploy: https://dev.to/rabeeaali/how-to-deploy-inertia-js-to-heroku-2cdn

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: If it helps I used this article to deploy: https://dev.to/rabeeaali/how-to-deploy-inertia-js-to-heroku-2cdn

Comment: I used Heroku's free option a year ago without diving deep into the details of how to deploy on it. But here is what I learned: **1** It uses PostgreSQL instead of MySQL **2** It returns unauthorized when an error happens in your code and you do not implement a custom way to handle that/catch the exception.

Comment: to be honest I really don't think it's the mysql fault, i already use mysql in other projects and I keep them at another server. It is probably something with the HTTPs, but I really don't know.

Comment: did you use MySQL on Heroku before? I guess that Laravel is trying to reach Heroku's PostgreSQL with MySQL settings